# How to create queries with subqueries in Symfony Doctrine

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, subquery, union

I want to make this sql query in doctrine:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
  (SELECT *, e1.stop_date as sort_date FROM `event` e1 WHERE ...) 
  UNION 
  (SELECT *, e2.start_date as sort_date FROM `event` e2 WHERE ...)
) e3 
ORDER BY e3.sort_date
```

And I want to result of symfony model connected to the event table, like using:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('Event')->createQuery('e')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try Doctrine's DQL languaje for complex queries:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('u.id')
        ->from('User u')
        ->where('u.id NOT IN (SELECT u2.id FROM User u2 INNER JOIN u2.Groups g)');

echo $q->getSqlQuery();
```

http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#subqueries

Or, alternatively, you can create a View in your database and use it as source table for simpler Doctrine queries.

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT * 
FROM (
  (SELECT *, e1.stop_date as sort_date FROM `event` e1 WHERE ...) 
  UNION 
  (SELECT *, e2.start_date as sort_date FROM `event` e2 WHERE ...)
) e3 
ORDER BY e3.sort_date
```

I've used both approachs in my projects and worked well, it depends on the way you access data, if you need to update, if you are allowed to create views, etc.